# Создание объектов в Python c разными именами

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать 12 одинаковых объектов с разными названиями?
Например, мне нужно, чтобы объекты располагались в 4 ряда, и назвались по координатам 11, 12, 13, 21 и т.д.
Возможно, имена можно брать из списка и создавать объект?

```
class MyClass():  
    objects = []  
    for a in range(1,4):  
        for b in range(1,3):  
            objects.append("obj_" + str(100*a + b))
```

Comment: В Python всё объекты. какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увидев что вы хотите сделать что-то ввиде карточной игры, думаю вам нужно что-то типа этого:

```
class CardDeck(object):  # класс колоды

    # Конструктор который принимает параметр количество строк и столбцов
    # по умолчанию 4 строки 3 столбца
    def __init__(self, rows=4, cols=3):
        self.deck = []
        self._generate_cards(rows, cols)

    def _generate_cards(self, rows, cols):
        # метод который генерирует карты
        # начинаем отсчёт с единички
        for row in range(1, rows + 1):
            card_row = []
            # можно добавить в список а можно даже убрать
            # тут уже на твоё усмотрение
            for col in range(1, cols + 1):
                # Добавляем нашу карту в список
                card_row.append(Card(row, col)) 
            # добавляем этот список в колоду
            self.deck.append(card_row)

    def print_out(self):
        # метод который выводит все карты на экран
        for r in self.deck:
            for card in r:
                print(card, end=" | ")
            print("")


class Card(object):
    # Объект для карты
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

    def __str__(self):
        return "Card row: {}, col: {}".format(self.row, self.col)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    deck = CardDeck()
    deck.print_out()
```

Запустив код получаем следющее:

```
Card row: 1, col: 1 | Card row: 1, col: 2 | Card row: 1, col: 3 | 
Card row: 2, col: 1 | Card row: 2, col: 2 | Card row: 2, col: 3 | 
Card row: 3, col: 1 | Card row: 3, col: 2 | Card row: 3, col: 3 | 
Card row: 4, col: 1 | Card row: 4, col: 2 | Card row: 4, col: 3 |
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Тогда возникает следующий вопрос: как обращаться к объектам, если они одинаково именуются. Например, как ИИ поймёт, какой именно объект ему нужно использовать?

Comment: Ну во первых, они вроде не одинаково именуются, и даже если у них будут одинаковые названия, то индекс у них никогда не будет одинаковым) Поэтому ИИ надо настроить так чтобы он искал по индексу и чекал название)

Answer (score 1):

А зачем Вам их называть?

Для цели организации переменных придумали массивы (в Питоне - списки). В данном случае элемент списка списков будет иметь два индекса, соответствующих положению в  ряду и колонке

```
 for a in range(1, 5):  
      objects.append([])
      for b in range(1, 4):  
          objects[a-1].append(чего-то там)
```

`objects[row][col]` однозначно характеризует объект.

Если объекты может перемещаться между позициями, ему можно добавить дополнительное свойство/поле -  оно может быть строкой

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать карточную игру. Есть изначальные метоположения, отличающиеся по характеристикам. К ним будет цепляться перемешанная колода карт. Соответственно, объекты - это местоположения, каждое из которых нужно обозвать, чтобы потом различать их свойства.

Comment: Имена переменных (точнее, новые переменные с нужными именами) в Питоне создать можно, но это эзотерика, и в данном случае она просто не нужна. Немного дополнил ответ.